# Cannot access deployed smart contract on mainnet

Tags: blockchain, ether, ethers.js, mainnet, hardhat

I tested my contract code on the Ropsten test network and everything seemed to work fine. I was able to run all my scripts and call functions on the contract on Ropsten. I then proceeded to deploy to the mainnet and etherscan says the contract deployment was successful: [Contract Etherscan link](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5bda09ef28686b701595b5ea7af8b2504827d864)

However I am unable to access the contract or any of its functions and I keep getting this error:

*Error: invalid hex string (argument="value", value="-0x02b4a8", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.0.10)
at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\marti\Martin\Projects\CEEU\node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:205:28)
at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\marti\Martin\Projects\CEEU\node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:217:20)
at Logger.throwArgumentError (C:\Users\marti\Martin\Projects\CEEU\node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:221:21)
at hexStripZeros (C:\Users\marti\Martin\Projects\CEEU\node_modules@ethersproject\bytes\src.ts\index.ts:296:16)
at Object.hexValue (C:\Users\marti\Martin\Projects\CEEU\node_modules@ethersproject\bytes\src.ts\index.ts:287:21)
at C:\Users\marti\Martin\Projects\CEEU\node_modules@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:547:27
at Array.forEach ()
at Function.JsonRpcProvider.hexlifyTransaction (C:\Users\marti\Martin\Projects\CEEU\node_modules@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:545:52)
at C:\Users\marti\Martin\Projects\CEEU\node_modules@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:186:60 {
reason: 'invalid hex string',
code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
argument: 'value',
value: '-0x02b4a8'
}*

Not really sure where the value is "-0x02b4a8" coming from. The code that calls the smart contract function is below:

```
const CEEU = (await bre.ethers.getContractFactory('CEEU')).connect(deployer)
const ceeuInstance = CEEU.attach(CEEUAddress)
await ceeuInstance.setMonetaryPolicy(PolicyAddress)
```

I know this code works because i tested on ropsten so i'm thinking that there is some mainnet config that i might be missing. but i'm relatively new to blockchain development so any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: The stack trace shows the error occuring in sendUncheckedTransaction function of json-rpc-provider.ts

```
sendUncheckedTransaction(transaction: Deferrable<TransactionRequest>): Promise<string> {
    transaction = shallowCopy(transaction);

    const fromAddress = this.getAddress().then((address) => {
        if (address) { address = address.toLowerCase(); }
        return address;
    });

    return resolveProperties({
        tx: resolveProperties(transaction),
        sender: fromAddress
    }).then(({ tx, sender }) => {
        if (tx.from != null) {
            if (tx.from.toLowerCase() !== sender) {
                logger.throwArgumentError("from address mismatch", "transaction", transaction);
            }
        } else {
            tx.from = sender;
        }

 // next line is where the stack trace show the error is coming from

        const hexTx = (<any>this.provider.constructor).hexlifyTransaction(tx, { from: true });

        return this.provider.send("eth_sendTransaction", [ hexTx ]).then((hash) => {
            return hash;
        }, (error) => {
            return checkError("sendTransaction", error, hexTx);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: The traceback mentions that it's getting the negative hex value at line 186 of your code - could you point to which line that is?

Comment: @TheRenaissance Updated the post with the stacktrace. The problem occurs when you try to convert the transaction object into hex format but i'm really baffled at where this  negative hex is coming from when i'm simply calling a function of the contract.

Comment: Did you ever work this out?

Answer (score 3):

This maybe due to your `gas` configuration in `hardhat.config.js`.
In my case I got the following error when upgrading a deployed smart contract in fuji network using `hardhat-upgrades` plugin.

`{reason: 'invalid hex string', code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT', argument: 'value', value: '-0x0ee98f'}`

and my config was,

```sh
fuji:{
  url: `https://api.avax-test.network/ext/bc/C/rpc`,
  accounts: [process.env.ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY],
  gas: 25,
  gasPrice: 30000000000,
},
```

After changing the `gas` the issue was solved.

```sh
fuji:{
  url: `https://api.avax-test.network/ext/bc/C/rpc`,
  accounts: [process.env.ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY],
  gas: 8000000,
  gasPrice: 30000000000,
},
```